# Lightbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-6, lightbox

How to display a div in lightbox dynamically using jquery on a button click? 
I wanna display the thank you message in lightbox in [this website](http://www.g2o.in) I tried it but IE6 is not supporting it. Please provide me a valid plugin.

Comment: must of plugins supports IE6+ only, if client not asked for IE6 better leave IE6.. use   http://fancybox.net/ or http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

Comment: Tamil? Join front-end developer chat room for more discussions http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19992/tamil-front-end-developers

Comment: @janani asking question/doubts on this way is not a recommended way on SO :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugins:

1. [fancybox.net](http://fancybox.net/)
2. [jacklmoore.com/colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox)